# Converting a string that is a bit Lisp-like to a Ruby array

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing

I have a string like this:

```
s = '+((((content:suspension) (content:sensor))~2) ((+(((content:susp) (content:sensor))~2)) (+(((content:height) (content:control) (content:sensor))~3)) (+(((content:height) (content:sensor))~2)) (+(((content:level) (content:control) (content:sensor))~3)) (+(((content:rear) (content:height) (content:sensor))~3)) (+(((content:ride) (content:height) (content:sensor))~3))))'
```

I'd like to convert it an array of strings that look like:

```
["suspension sensor", "susp sensor", "height control sensor", "height sensor", "level control sensor", "rear height sensor", "ride height sensor"]
```

Here is a very ugly bit of code that accomplishes that:

```
a = s.gsub('content:', '') \
  .gsub(/\+/, '') \
  .gsub(/~\d/, '') \
  .gsub(/\((\w+)\)/) { $1 } \
  .gsub(/\(([^\(]*[^\)])\)/) { "#{$1}" } \
  .gsub(/[\(\)]/,', ') \
  .split(/\s?,\s?/) \
  .reject {|x| x.strip == ''}
```

I think there must be a much nicer way of doing this, given that if you take out the `content:` prefix and the `+` and `~\d` pieces, then it's just like a Lisp expression.

Comment: Interesting format. The `~n` designators appear to be redundant (since the parentheses already determine how many are grouped)? Or do they add any further significance? And it appears you are wanting to ignore any other structure above that?

Comment: The [Sexpistol library](https://github.com/aarongough/sexpistol) can parse normally-written S-expressions (sexps) into arrays.

Comment: @mbratch the ~2 is a 'boost'.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane I'll take a look at Sexpistol too, though I think for this a simple regex is all I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s.gsub(/\(content:([^(]*)\)/, '\1').scan(/(?<=\()[^()]*(?=\))/)

# => ["suspension sensor", "susp sensor", "height control sensor", "height sensor", "level control sensor", "rear height sensor", "ride height sensor"]
```

Comment: That looks perfect. I was just trying to come up with something using scan, but this bit is key: ([^(]*)\). Thanks again.